# Remove Decimals from String

Tags: java, format, bigdecimal

I have a function that converst a BigDecimal into a String plus the currency. When  I use this the number (e.g. 34) turns into a number with a lot of decimals (e.g. 34.000000).

What can I do to solve this and just show the 34?

Here is my function:

```
    row.put("Money", GcomNullPointerValidator.isNullField(formatUtils.formatCurrency(MoneyDto.getAmount().stripTrailingZeros())));
```

Comment: Without seeing what these functions do it'll be hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the language? Java?
You can use the split() function of String if you just want to keep numbers before "." :

```
String mystring = "34.000000";
String correctstring[] = mystring.split(".");
System.out.println(correctstring[0]);
// display : 34
```

**it will delete all digits after "."** !

Comment: Error. You should escape the regex. `String correctstring[] = mystring.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your method that converts a BigDecimal into a String, you can use BigDecimal.setScale() to set the number of digits after the decimal point. For example:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("34.000000");
BigDecimal d1 = d.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // yields 34.00
BigDecimal d2 = d.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // yields 34
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String number = "150.000";
number.replaceAll("\\.\\d+$", "");
```

Or you can use this:

```
number.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0];
```

Comment: awesome thank you. This worked number.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0];